# Isomorphism $M_1/N_1 \otimes M_2/N_2 \cong (M_1 \otimes M_2)/(N_1 \otimes M_2 + M_1 \otimes N_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

My understanding of bilinear functions is a bit sketchy so this is possibly a very dumb question. I'm reading a book which contains the following proposition (all of the tensor products in this question are over $R$).

> Let $M_1, M_2$ be $R$-modules and let $N_1$ (respectively $N_2$) be an $R$-submodule of $M_1$ (respectively $M_2$). Then there is an isomorphism of $R$-modules:
> \begin{equation} M_1/N_1 \otimes M_2/N_2 \cong (M_1 \otimes M_2)/(N_1 \otimes M_2 + M_1 \otimes N_2). \end{equation}

Here $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. We first note that there is an obvious $R$-bilinear map:
\begin{equation} h:M_1 \times M_2 \rightarrow M_1/N_1 \otimes M_2/N_2 \end{equation} defined by $h(a,b) = (a + N_1) \otimes (b + N_2)$. Then, by the definition of a tensor product, we have a map:
\begin{equation} \tilde{h} : M_1 \otimes M_2 \rightarrow M_1/N_1 \otimes M_2/N_2 \end{equation}
defined by $\tilde{h}(a \otimes b) = (a + N_1) \otimes (b + N_2)$.

So far, this all makes sense. The next step, which is not explained, is to notice that $N_1 \otimes_R M_2 + M_1 \otimes N_2 \subseteq \ker(\tilde{h})$. I don't see why this is the case.

For example, let $n \otimes b + a \otimes m \in N_1 \otimes M_2 + M_1 \otimes N_2$, with $n \in N_1$, $m \in N_2$, $a \in M_1$ and $b \in M_2$. Then:
\begin{align}
\tilde{h}(n \otimes b + a \otimes m) &= \tilde{h}\left( (n + a)\otimes(b + m) \right) \\
&= \left( (n+a) + N_1\right) \otimes \left((b + m) + N_2\right) \\
&= (a + N_1) \otimes (b + N_2)
\end{align}
But this is not the identity $N_1 \otimes N_2$, unless $a \in N_1$ and $b \in N_2$ which isn't the case in general.

Can anyone explain where my reasoning has gone wrong? I'm sure that I'm either misunderstanding how tensors work, but maybe there's some other aspect of the setup that I've overlooked.

Comment: See Theorem 2.19 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf, where the surjective linear maps $\varphi$ and $\psi$ out of $M$ and $N$ there are the standard reduction maps $M_1 \to M_1/N_1$ and $M_2 \to M_2/N_2$ in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your equality is incorrect; we do not have $n\otimes b+a\otimes m=(n+a)\otimes(b+m)$.

Instead you could use linearity of $\tilde{h}$:
$$\tilde{h}(n\otimes b+a\otimes m) = \tilde{h}(n\otimes b)+\tilde{h}(a\otimes m) = (n+N_1)\otimes(b+N_2)+(a+N_1)\otimes(m+N_2).$$

Comment: Ah, I think I assumed that $\tilde{h}$ was bilinear. Am I correct to say that, if $\tilde{h}$ was bilinear, we would have $\tilde{h}(n \otimes b) + \tilde{h}(a \otimes m) = \tilde{h}((n + a)\otimes(b + m))$?

Comment: $\tilde{h}$ is a function on *one* argument, so it cannot be *bi*linear. The related function $h$ is the one that is bilinear since it has *two* arguments. You can think of the tensor product as being sort of like multiplication of real numbers; try comparing $nb+am$ to $(n+a)(b+m)$ if $n,b,a,m$ were just real numbers. Are they the same?

Comment: For your interest, I remember that the result in the title is usually proved via diagram chasing, by drawing a $3\times 3$ diagram of short exact sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dave, I clearly need to stop thinking of tensor products as just a "cartesian product with extra steps". Given that I can't just combine the result of $N_1 \otimes (b + N_2) + (a + N_1) \otimes N_2$, how can we see that this is $N_1 \otimes N_2$ (i.e. that $n \otimes b  + a \otimes m$ is in the kernel of $\tilde{h}$)?

Comment: Look at the $n+N_1$ and $m+N_2$ parts on the right side of the equality in my answer.

Comment: Ah, you have this written in your comment. But this is it, e.g. in the first term you have $N_1\otimes(b+N_2)$, but what is $N_1$ in $M_1/N_1$?

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure if this is correct, but $N_1$ is the identity in $M_1/N_1$, so $0$. Then $N_1 \otimes (b + N_2) = (0 \otimes b + N_2) = 0$ in $M_1/N_1 \otimes M_2/N_2$? If that's right then the same holds for the other term, so we get $0 + 0 = 0$.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: @Dave thank you for your patience, this all makes sense now.